# How to rotate a PictureBox on a windows form using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to rotate a picture box 180 degrees when a condition in my if statement is met. Is this possible?

Comment: The picture box itself or just the contained image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll assume that you want to rotate the image inside, because rotating the box itself doesn't make much sense (and is impossible anyway).

Try this:

```
myPictureBox.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)
PictureBox1.Refresh()
```

When you try to rotate your image with:

```
PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)
```

nothing will happen until you close the form and open it again (not the project, just the form). If you want to rotate at once then you should use `PictureBox1.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 2):

The System.Drawing.Image.RotateFlip() method allows you to rotate the actual image displayed in the picturebox.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip(VS.80).aspx)

```
Dim bitmap1 As Bitmap

Private Sub InitializeBitmap()
    Try
        bitmap1 = CType(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\" _
            & "Documents\My Music\music.bmp"), Bitmap)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        PictureBox1.Image = bitmap1
    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Check the path to the bitmap.")
    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If bitmap1 IsNot Nothing Then
   bitmap1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY)
        PictureBox1.Image = bitmap1
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You  grasp the concepts for C++ as given in
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/rimage.aspx
and may use for VB.net as given in
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/14/10053817/rotating-picturebox-contr.aspx

Comment: Thes sites were helpful - Thanks!